# Извлечь значения из массива

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется массив данных:

```
[array([ 0.26506782], dtype=float32), array([ 0.11561533], dtype=float32), array([ 0.07030345], dtype=float32), array([ 0.30478492], dtype=float32), array([ 0.65996456], dtype=float32), array([ 0.19159396], dtype=float32), array([ 0.33576787], dtype=float32), array([ 0.14348345], dtype=float32), array([ 0.32245761], dtype=float32), array([ 0.46053874], dtype=float32), array([ 0.30267289], dtype=float32), array([ 0.24920712], dtype=float32), array([ 0.44585139], dtype=float32), array([ 0.26151684], dtype=float32), array([ 0.02548757], dtype=float32), array([ 0.33207515], dtype=float32)]
```

Как мне извлечь из него все числовые значения?

В итоге я хочу получить список из значений:

```
list = [0.26506782,0.11561533,0.07030345,0.30478492, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [9]: res = np.asarray(l).ravel().tolist()

In [10]: res
Out[10]:
[0.26506781578063965,
 0.11561533063650131,
 0.07030344754457474,
 0.3047849237918854,
 0.6599645614624023,
 0.1915939599275589,
 0.33576786518096924,
 0.14348344504833221,
 0.32245761156082153,
 0.46053874492645264,
 0.3026728928089142,
 0.24920712411403656,
 0.4458513855934143,
 0.26151683926582336,
 0.025487570092082024,
 0.3320751488208771]
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как мне привести к виду, чтобы я мог заменить значения в этом массиве?

Comment: @Midnight, укажите в вопросе что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: @Midnight, я думаю вам стоит описать вопрос шире, чтобы было понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать. Хранить Numpy массивы в виде обычного Python списка - не самая лучшая идея...

Comment: мне нужно превратить данный массив с писок и замнеить значения меньше 0.5 на 0, и больше на 1

Comment: @Midnight, приведите в __вопросе__ _небольшой_ пример входных и выходных данных. Все детали, касающиеся вопроса, должны быть в вопросе, а не в комментариях...

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Midnight, чтобы округлить до целых используйте `np.round(res)`